# Reduce file size of ffmpeg converted video

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have a .**mp4** video with a file size of **540kb** and a duration of 30 seconds before it was converted, but when I use **ffmpeg** to convert it to the file size became **21mb**. What options do I need to add inorder to reduce the file size to less than **1mb**?

ffmpeg command I am using right now:

```
video_filename = __DIR__.  '/uploads/VID.mp4';

exec('ffmpeg -i '.$video_filename.' -c:v libx264 '.$video_filename.'');
```

Comment: Try adding -crf {number}, higher number = less quality: 
exec('ffmpeg -i '.$video_filename.' -c:v libx264 -crf 25 '.$video_filename.'');

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov How can I replace the existing file? for example the file name is video.mp4 and the output name is also video.mp4? How can I replace the existing file? I want to replace the original file but when I use the command the file is not replacing

Comment: It's not impossible to directly overwrite the existing file. You need to temporarily store the output in other location or rename it.

Comment: Overwriting the input file will truncate and damage the input file which will result in damaged output file!

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov how can I overwrite the file properly?

Answer (score 1):

Create tmp_dir in the desired location

```
exec('ffmpeg -i '.$video_filename.' -c:v libx264 -crf 25 tmp_dir'.$video_filename.'');
exec('rm -rf '. $video_filename);
exec('mv tmp_dir/'.$video_filename.' ..');
```

I hope it will work properly, I haven't test it!.